# R xml POST parallel pasuing

Tags: r, xml, parallel-processing

I am using R's XML, parallel and several other libraries to download data from a government API.

I am using multiple cores to post multiple XML files over each one.

I am parsing the response and appending it to a CSV file every time I get a response.

for some reason, the post and response just stops every day at 23:23.
i don't seem to be able to locate the reason this is happening.
i tried running the script using all 12 cores, then 7, and now 4 and it keeps happening.

the warning messages are all normal concerning the disconnection from the server or from the files.

we don't have a memory problem, and the process is working on another computer with less xml files, each on its own core.

these are the libraries i am using

```
library(magrittr)
library(httr)
library(xml2)
library(plyr)
library(XML)
library(parallel)
library(data.table)
library(compiler)

#defining the parameters to begin with  
initialise <- function(){ 

  setwd("D:/Users/GAMESuser/Desktop/siri")
  MOTurl <<- "http://siri.motrealtime.co.il:8081/Siri/SiriServices"

  path_to_xml_1 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro1.xml"
  path_to_xml_2 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro2.xml"
  path_to_xml_3 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro3.xml"
  path_to_xml_4 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro4.xml"
  path_to_xml_5 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro5.xml"
  path_to_xml_6 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro6.xml"
  path_to_xml_7 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro7.xml"
  path_to_xml_8 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro8.xml"
  path_to_xml_9 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro9.xml"
  path_to_xml_10 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro10.xml"
  path_to_xml_11 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro11.xml"
  path_to_xml_12 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro12.xml"
  path_to_xml_13 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro13.xml"
  path_to_xml_14 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro14.xml"
  path_to_xml_15 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro15.xml"
  path_to_xml_16 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro16.xml"
  path_to_xml_17 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro17.xml"
  path_to_xml_18 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro18.xml"
  path_to_xml_19 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro19.xml"
  path_to_xml_20 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro20.xml"
  path_to_xml_21 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro21.xml"
  path_to_xml_22 <<- "xml_TLV_metro/TAmetro22.xml"

 #using a maximal column names table for rbindlist   

  LoopTime <<- Sys.time()
  DFall <<- data.frame(matrix(rep("a",22),ncol = 22, nrow = 1)) #set empty df with all column names
  colnames(DFall) <<- colnames(read.csv("colnames.csv"))

  ToWriteFile <<- TRUE
  dateForFileName <<- Sys.Date()

#creating the temporary csv files

  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro3.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro4.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro5.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro6.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro7.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro8.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro9.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro10.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro11.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(DFall, "TAmetro12.csv", row.names = FALSE)



  request_ID <<- 0 


  teststart <<- Sys.time()

}

getDataFromServer <-  function(pathnumlist, k, Ctime){
  list_node <- list()
  #list_node[[1]] <- 1
  force(k)
  force(DFall)
  list_node[[1]] <- DFall
  i<-2
  qq = 0
  listOfCalls <- list()
  Call_time_to_server <-as.character(as.POSIXct(strptime(Ctime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
  for(xmls in pathnumlist){
    qq = qq + 1
    x1 = POST(MOTurl, body = upload_file(xmls), add_headers('Content-Type' = 'text/xml'))
    testend <- Sys.time()
    print(paste("post time: ", testend - teststart))


    listOfCalls[[qq]] <- x1
  }


   for(callnum in listOfCalls){

     content <- content(callnum) %>% as.character() %>% read_xml()
     nodes <- xml_find_all(content,"//ns3:MonitoredStopVisit")
     # loop relevant fields

     for(levent in nodes){
       keys <- c(levent %>% xml_children() %>% xml_name(),
                 levent %>% xml_children() %>% xml_children() %>% xml_name(),
                 levent %>% xml_children() %>% xml_children()%>% xml_children() %>% xml_name())
       values <- c(levent %>% xml_children() %>% xml_text(),
                   levent %>% xml_children() %>% xml_children() %>% xml_text(),
                   levent %>% xml_children() %>% xml_children()%>% xml_children() %>% xml_text())
       # list as keys and values
       event <- setNames(as.list(values),keys)
       event[["request_id"]] <- k
       # append to list
       event[["call_time_toServer"]] <- Call_time_to_server
       event[["MonitoredVehicleJourney"]] <- NULL
       event[["VehicleLocation"]] <- NULL
       event[["MonitoredCall"]] <- NULL


       if(is.null(event$VehicleRef) | is.null(event$RecordedAtTime) | is.null(event$Latitude))
       {

       }
       else
       {
         if(length(list_node) > 10 & (any(sapply(list_node,function(x) x$RecordedAtTime==event$RecordedAtTime &
                       x$VehicleRef == event$VehicleRef)))){

         }
          else
         {
          list_node[[i]] <- event #as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(event), nrow=length(unlist(event)))))
          i <- i+1
         }
       }
     }
   }
  return(list_node)
}
getDataFromServerc <- cmpfun(getDataFromServer)
initialise()
z <- 0

 #the tasks are currently running with all xml files because we need them all, the way they are distributed is meaningless to us
Tasks <<- list(
  job1 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(path_to_xml_1,path_to_xml_2,path_to_xml_15,path_to_xml_11,path_to_xml_12,path_to_xml_19), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime), ## out[[1]]
  job2 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(path_to_xml_3,path_to_xml_4,path_to_xml_16,path_to_xml_20,path_to_xml_9,path_to_xml_10), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime), ## out[[2]]
  job3 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(path_to_xml_5,path_to_xml_6,path_to_xml_17,path_to_xml_21,path_to_xml_22), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime),
  job4 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(path_to_xml_7,path_to_xml_8,path_to_xml_18,path_to_xml_13,path_to_xml_14), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime)
  # job5 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime),
  # job6 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime),
  # job7 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime)
  # job8 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(path_to_xml_15,path_to_xml_16), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime),
  # job9 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(path_to_xml_17,path_to_xml_18), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime),
  # job10 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(path_to_xml_19,path_to_xml_20), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime),
  # job11 <- function() getDataFromServerc(pathnumlist = list(path_to_xml_21,path_to_xml_22), k = request_ID, Ctime = CallTime)
 )


cl <<- makeCluster(length(Tasks), type = "PSOCK")
clusterEvalQ(cl,c(library(httr),library(XML),library(magrittr),library(xml2)))
clusterExport(cl, as.list(ls()), envir=environment())



while(TRUE){
  gc()

  if(as.numeric(Sys.time()-LoopTime,units="secs")< 10)
  {
    print("sleeping")
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }
  LoopTime <- Sys.time()

  testend <- Sys.time()
  print(paste("write time: " ,testend - teststart))
  teststart <- Sys.time()
  CallTime <- Sys.time()
  request_ID <- request_ID + 1
  tryCatch({  # conintue dispite error (to test...)

 ## use multicore
    cl <<- makeCluster(length(Tasks), type = "PSOCK")
    clusterEvalQ(cl,c(library(httr),library(XML),library(magrittr),library(xml2)))
    clusterExport(cl, list("MOTurl", "path_to_xml_1","path_to_xml_2","path_to_xml_3","path_to_xml_4", "path_to_xml_5","path_to_xml_6","path_to_xml_7","path_to_xml_8","path_to_xml_9","path_to_xml_10","path_to_xml_11","path_to_xml_12","path_to_xml_13","path_to_xml_14","path_to_xml_15","path_to_xml_16","path_to_xml_17","path_to_xml_18","path_to_xml_19","path_to_xml_20","path_to_xml_21","path_to_xml_22", "getDataFromServer","getDataFromServerc", "teststart", "testend"), envir=environment())
    clusterExport(cl, list("request_ID", "CallTime","DFall"))
    out <- clusterApply(
      cl,
      Tasks,
      function(f) f()
    )


    for(out_x in 1:4){
      name.for.temp.file <- paste0("TAmetro",out_x,".csv")
        outlist_1 <-out[[out_x]]
        DFoutput_1 <- rbindlist(outlist_1, fill = TRUE)
        write.table(DFoutput_1[2:nrow(DFoutput_1),],file = name.for.temp.file, append = TRUE, eol = "\n", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
    }

    rm(out)
    stopCluster(cl)
    rm(cl)
    print(paste("request_ID:",request_ID))
    },error = function(e){cat("continued dispite ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")}
  )


  # if function runs for 24 hours save.
  if (strftime(Sys.time(), "%H") == "02" & ToWriteFile)
  {

    ToWriteFile = FALSE
    print("WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW")
    tryCatch({  # conintue dispite error (to test...)

      z = z +1
      teststart <- Sys.time()
      DFmetro1 <- read.csv("TAmetro1.csv")
      DFmetro2 <- read.csv("TAmetro2.csv")
      DFmetro3 <- read.csv("TAmetro3.csv")
      DFmetro4 <- read.csv("TAmetro4.csv")
      DFmetro5 <- read.csv("TAmetro5.csv")
      DFmetro6 <- read.csv("TAmetro6.csv")
      DFmetro7 <- read.csv("TAmetro7.csv")
      DFmetro8 <- read.csv("TAmetro8.csv")
      DFmetro9 <- read.csv("TAmetro9.csv")
      DFmetro10 <- read.csv("TAmetro10.csv")
      DFmetro11 <- read.csv("TAmetro11.csv")
      DFmetro12 <- read.csv("TAmetro12.csv")



      DFoutput_METRO <- rbind(DFmetro1,DFmetro2,DFmetro3,DFmetro4,DFmetro5,DFmetro6,DFmetro7,DFmetro8,DFmetro9,DFmetro10,DFmetro11,DFmetro12)


      testend <- Sys.time()
      rbindtime <-  as.character(paste("rbind performed in:" , testend - teststart))

      nameforFile = paste0("DFTAmetro",dateForFileName,"_",z)


       ts1 <- Sys.time()
      write.csv(DFoutput_METRO,paste0("D:\\Users\\GAMESuser\\Desktop\\siri\\Metro\\",nameforFile,".csv"))

      te1 <- Sys.time()
      WriteCSVtime <- as.character(paste("csv saved in:" , te1 - ts1))

      write(x = paste0(rbindtime, " ",WriteCSVtime), file = paste0("times",Sys.Date(),"_",z, '.txt') )

      ts3 <- Sys.time()
      saveRDS(DFoutput_METRO, file = paste(nameforFile,".rds"))

      te3 <- Sys.time()
      print(paste("rds saved in:" , te3 - ts3))

      print ("finish writing all metro!!!!!")
    },error = function(e){cat("continued dispite ERROR in writing to file for line 7 :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})

    LoopTime = Sys.time()

    rm(DFmetro1 ,DFmetro2,DFmetro3,DFmetro4,DFmetro5, DFmetro6,DFmetro7 ,DFmetro8 ,DFmetro9 ,DFmetro10 ,DFmetro11,DFmetro12, outlist_1,DFoutput_METRO)
    gc()


    ### get gtfs file for the day

    tryCatch({  # conintue dispite error (to test...)   get GTFS
      GTFSdate <- Sys.Date(); GTFSdate <- as.character(as.POSIXct(strptime(GTFSdate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")));
      GTFSfile_name <- as.character(paste("GTFS",GTFSdate,".zip", sep = "")) ;
      download.file("ftp://gtfs.mot.gov.il/israel-public-transportation.zip", destfile = paste0("D:\\Users\\GAMESuser\\Desktop\\siri\\GTFSdaily\\",GTFSfile_name), method = "libcurl")


    },error = function(e){cat("continued dispite ERROR in writing to file for line 7 :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
    print ("finish downlading GTFS!!!!!")
  }

  if (strftime(Sys.time(), "%H") == "04"){
    initialise()

  }
}
```

does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
we checked for the posobility of the antivirus hampering on the mutiple cores but it didn't check out.

*NOTE: R doesnt stop or freeze. it just appears to be running without writing to file or posting to server. i can see the time it stopped by the last change in the temporary files.

Comment: I kinda hope it's their web service that's detecting abuse and preventing you from doing this effectively. Your description sure sounds like you don't care at all about the load on that server.

Comment: we do post a lot of requests, but it should work. and note, this works perfectly during rush hours, but simply stops at 23:23 for some reason.